# Optimizing table structure for logging data over time

Tags: php, mysql

It's about a website that has like 10 product feeds. The feeds are imported multiple times per day. At each import phase I want to save in a table the `sku` and the `price` of each item (in order to alert through mail if price dropped beyond 10% let's say).

At the moment I store this data as follows:

```
primary_key   sku     price datetime
1             XYX     1     2015-04-02 20:10:59  
2             ZYZ     2     2015-04-02 20:10:59
3             XYX     2     2015-04-03 20:10:59
4             XYX     0.5   2015-04-04 20:10:59
```

For the sku `XYX` the price evolution is 1 -> 2 -> 0.5 . At this stage I want to send a warning mail. I know how to do it. The problem is That with each product feed the table grows with about 50.000 rows. When trying to get the result through a query like:

```
SELECT sku,
       group_concat(cast(price as char(10)) separator '->') 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY sku 
ORDER BY datetime
```

... it takes at least 5 seconds. While the time passes, the table will have even more rows and the query time will raise. I can delete the records older than 4 days for example (because of weekends).

I was thinking of making this table as follows:

```
id    sku    price
1     XYX    1->2->3->2.3
2     VZV    5->6->5->5.5
```

... but in this case I won't be "able" to delete old records by date and the price column will have to be text/blob which probably will have big impact on the query time combined (php + mysql).

What would be the fastest running query?

Thanks!

Comment: A lot of data uses a lot of space. A lot of data needs a lot of time to process it. It looks to me like you've got the right structure right now.

Comment: you need to add index on sku and price columns.  Indexes help optimize query execution.

Comment: @user2411276: adding index on `sku` only crashes the script with "Internal server error", I've tried that.

Comment: The server is crashing because it is a live table.  This table is constantly updated and cannot be locked to add the index by the engine.

Comment: I suggest you create another table which is also updated as soon as data is inserted into this live table.  And indexes can be added to it and  any report can be pulled against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a well known performance issue with `group_concat`, but using `DISTINCT` which is not your case.

Try **adding an index** to `price` column:

```
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD INDEX `price` (`price`)
```

Since is the one using `group_concat` and run the query to check if the performance is better. Also, I would follow @symcbean advice.

Another solution is **having two single column indexes**, as @user2411276 suggest.

If you have an index with two columns, the query might be faster (you should measure). A two column index can also be used as a single column index, but only for the column listed first.

Sometimes it can be useful to have an index on (A,B) and another index on (B). This makes queries using either or both, but uses also more disk space.

When choosing the indexes, you also need to consider the effect on inserting, deleting and updating. **More indexes, slower updates**, so start testing and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Create index on sku and price columns:

```
alter table <table_name> add INDEX indx_sku (sku,price);
```

Comment: This won't make the only query valicu2000 has posted go any faster.

Answer (score 1):

While there is an argument for storing multiple values in the same row (multiple fields), most people would agree that this should be a last resort when a properly normalised solution cannot meet your needs, however I doubt anyone with any significant experience with relational databases would think that putting multiple values into the same field is ever a good idea.

Are you having performance problems now? If so then post another question with the queries, schema and explain plans.

The query you've shown us here will be reading several million rows, so, yes, it will take time. There is probably a lot of scope for optimising the schema/processing, e.g. only adding a record when the price of an SKU has changed, but this could have a lot of impact elsewhere.